# How to display two shape result on a single page in Orchard?

Tags: c#-4.0, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Using below code, I have two shape results:

```
public ActionResult CompareRevisions(List<String> Ids)
{
  contentItemLeft = // code to get a ContentItem         
  contentItemRight = // code to get a ContentItem
  dynamic modelLeft = Services.ContentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItemLeft);
  dynamic modelRight = Services.ContentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItemRight);
  var ctx = Services.WorkContext;
   ctx.Layout.Metadata.Alternates.Add("Layout_Null");
   var shapeResultLeft = new ShapeResult(this, modelLeft);
   var shapeResultRight = new ShapeResult(this, modelRight);
   return shapeResultLeft;
}
```

When I return any of one shape result such as `return shapeResultLeft` at the last line of Controller,  the browser displays perfectly the Content. However How can I display both of my ShapeResults: `shapeResultLeft` , `shapeResultRight`  on the Page same time ?

How do I return a list of ShapeResults and display it using the View/Layout file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple options for this:

**Method 1**

one most used in MVC (not Orchard specific) is a viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public dynamic Shape1 { get; set; }
    public dynamic Shape2 { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult CompareRevisions(List<String> Ids) {
    // ..
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel {
        Shape1 = modelLeft,
        Shape2 = modelRight
    }
    return View(viewModel)
}
```

view:

```
@model My.NameSpace.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@Display(Model.Shape1)
@Display(Model.Shape2)
```

**Method 2**

Without using strongly typed viewmodels, you can use orchard's dynamic viewmodel:

```
// inject IShapeFactory through Dependency Injection
public MyController(IShapeFactory shapeFactory) {
    Shape = shapeFactory;
}

public dynamic Shape { get; set; } // inject with DI through IShapeFactory

public ActionResult CompareRevisions(List<String> Ids) {
    // ..
    var viewModel = Shape
        .ViewModel() // dynamic
        .Shape1(modelLeft)
        .Shape2(modelRight);

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Method 3**

Or with Orchard's list, when the number of shapes could vary:

```
public dynamic Shape { get; set; } // inject with DI through IShapeFactory

public ActionResult CompareRevisions(List<String> Ids) {
    // ..
    var list = Shape.List();
    list.AddRange(myShapes); // myShapes is a collection of build shapes (modelLeft, modelRight)

    var viewModel = Shape
        .ViewModel()
        .List(list);

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

view:

```
@Display(Model.List);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is meant by " inject with DI through IShapeFactory "? what is DI ? . Iam just a newbie, my apologies for asking this little details

Comment: And there are yet other options where you send your shapes to other top-level zones than the content zone: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/dispatching-orchard-shapes-to-arbitrary-zones  (this example is doing it from a driver, but should also work from a controller action)

Comment: @bertrand wouldnt or be much simpler to use placement for that?

Comment: The post was written before placement was extended to work with top-level zones, but in this specific case, no, you can't use placement for any shapes, only those coming from drivers invoked as part of the rendering of a content item. Won't work from a controller that I know of.